# How to receive the response of a server into a string variable using c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, visual-studio-2015, winsock

I'm writing a console application using c++ with sockets. I need to receive the response not into a char array but into a string. The problem is that I don't know how to do it. Someone know the answer? Thanks to all.

Now I've this code:

```
    char buffer[1000000];
    int nDataLength;
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 1000000, 0)) > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            cout << buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }
```

I need to translate *buffer* into a string before to receive data because if I use the char array the buffer isn't enought big to store the entaire result and if I increase the size, *Visuale Studio* show me an error with the initialization of the socket

I use :

```
WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname("www.site.com");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
```

This is the way beacuse I need to store the response into a string but: *How can I do it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate ( join together ) a `string variable` with a `char buffer`  in  your loop like this:

```
 myString+=buffer[i];   // myString = myString + buffer[i];
```

Example code listing:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

string myString;
locale local;


//***************************
void getWebsite(char *url );
//***************************


int main (){


    getWebsite("www.google.com" );
    for (size_t i=0; i<myString.length(); ++i) myString[i]= tolower(myString[i],local);

    cout <<myString;

    return 0;
}



//***************************
void getWebsite(char *url ){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET Socket;
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;


    int lineCount=0;
    int rowCount=0;

    struct hostent *host;
    char *getHttp= new char[256];

        memset(getHttp,' ', sizeof(getHttp) );
        strcpy(getHttp,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ");
        strcat(getHttp,url);
        strcat(getHttp,"\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");

        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0){
            cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
            system("pause");
            //return 1;
        }

         Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);


        host = gethostbyname(url);

        SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
        SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

        cout << "Connecting...\n";
            if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
                cout << "Could not connect";
                system("pause");
                //return 1;
            }
        cout << "Connected.\n";

        //send(Socket,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cplusplus.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"),0);

        send(Socket,getHttp, strlen(getHttp),0 );

        char buffer[10000];

        int nDataLength;
            while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket,buffer,10000,0)) > 0) {       
                int i = 0;

                while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {

                    myString+=buffer[i];  // myString = myString + buffer[i];
                    i += 1;
                }


            }
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();

        delete[] getHttp;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you're getting a +1 from me for putting up a complete, working example with expected results; even though you committed a cardinal sin by using raw new/delete in place of smart pointers... For some reason though, the OP seems to want to remove white space from his results.

Comment: @Software_Designer your code work but if I insert path to get the page whole page doesn't arrive..  I say this: `strcpy(getHttp, "GET /cerca?q=pasta HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ");`

Answer (score 2):

ok, let's be reasonable and get rid of that ridiculously huge buffer.

```
char buffer[4096];
int nDataLength;
std::string result;
while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 4096, 0)) > 0) {
    std::copy_if(buffer, buffer + nDataLength, 
                 std::back_inserter(result),
                 [](char c) { 
                     return !std::isspace(c);
                     // maybe you wanted this instead?
                     // return std::isprint(c);
                 });
}
// result now contains your string, without any white space
```

Comment: but for `copy_if` , `back_inserter` and `isspace` what libraries should I include? @RichardHodges

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
const std::ssize_t max_size = 1000000;
std::string buffer();
buffer.resize(max_size);

// and use where you need:
ssize_t new_size = recv(Socket, &buffer[0], max_size, 0);
buffer.resize (new_size);
```

Because `std::string` has no fixed size (and possibly null), you have to be sure that memory is allocated. Here, I use `resize()` function of `std::string` to be sure to have enough memory inside string. And after filling string, you have to resize manually string.

BUT `recv` is a plain old C function, so it simply can't resize `std::string` by itself!

Another solution is to allocate small char array and concatenate it to a final std::string which contains global response :

```
std::final final;

// retrieve small char array of max_size, for example equal to 256

final += std::string (buffer, max_size);
```

Comment: std::string::reserve reserves space but does not change the `length()` of the string. The first answer is incorrect.

Comment: It's still not right. buffer has been default-constructed. calling reserve() on it changes nothing. it's still of length zero. addressing *(&buffer[0]) [which recv will do] is therefore undefined behaviour.

Comment: @RichardHodges corrected again, hoping it's good now. Thank you very much for correcting me!

Comment: That'll fix it. Still - a million characters though... and you haven't yet taken into account the fact that the op wants to remove white space.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the storage space is the actually issue, a chained buffer approach could be a solution.

```
#define MAX_BUF_LEN 10000
typedef struct netBuf
{
     char data[MAX_BUF_LEN];
     struct netBuf * pNext;
} NET_BUF;

NET_BUF * pHead = NULL;
NET_BUF *pCurrent = malloc(sizeof(NET_BUF));
pCurrent->pNext = NULL:
pHead = pCurrent;

char * pData = pCurrent->data;
int nDataLength;
int dataToRead = MAX_BUF_LEN;

while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, pData, dataToRead, 0)) > 0) {
    if(dataToRead == nDataLength)
    {
        pCurrent->pNext = malloc(sizeof(NET_BUF));
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
        pCurrent->pNext = NULL;
        pData = pCurrent->data;
        dataToRead = MAX_BUF_LEN;
    }
    else
    {
        dataToRead -= nDataLength;
        pData +=nDataLength;
    }

}
```